# How do I change the way I highlight text in Android Studios in mac?

Tags: android, macos, highlighting

I have a pretty weird problem. I am currently using Android Studios on a MacBook Pro, and when I mark my text (by clicking and dragging the cursor), it does not highlight the text row by row. Instead, it marks the text exactly as I move the cursor, without any consideration of the lines. Does anyone know how to change this, so I mark the text in the normal way, so if I move the cursor three lines up it marks the whole lines and not just a part of the lines?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I just restarted the program.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you got stuck in *[Column Selection Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1395590e297)*.  Since this happens to me on occasion, to fix uncheck "Column Selection Mode" from the *Edit* menu.

Answer (score 8):

That is Column Selection Mode. It is actually very useful. You can edit multiple lines at once. [See it in action here](https://github.com/pavlospt/Android-Studio-Tips-by-Philippe-Breault/wiki/Column-Selection)

To toggle it on/off:

- Right Click -> Column Select Mode

*or*

- <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>